# Pester mock error PSInvalidCastException on Azure cmdlet call

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, azure, mocking, pester

I need to "Pester-test" 2 Azure cmdlets, **Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup** and **Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule** from a PowerShell function inside a module, that looks like following:

```
  $nsg = Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NsgName
  Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule -Name $NsgRule.name `
      -Type Outbound `
      # ... other properties here ... 
      -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg |
    Format-List -Property Name,Location,Label
```

The parameters $NsgName, $NsgRule are not so important, the problem is I receive errors when mocking Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule like:

```
Mock Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup { return [PSCustomObject] @{ Name='Any' } }
Mock Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule
Mock Format-List
```

The error says:

```
 [-] Error occurred in Describe block 100ms
   PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert the "@{Name=Any}" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Network.NetworkSecurityGroup.Model.INetworkSecurityGroup".
   ArgumentTransformationMetadataException: Cannot convert the "@{Name=Any}" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Network.NetworkSecurityGroup.Model.INetworkSecurityGroup".
   ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'NetworkSecurityGroup'. Cannot convert the "@{Name=Any}" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Network.NetworkSecurityGroup.Model.INetworkSecurityGroup".
```

It's quite clear what's happening, the issue is I don't know how to mock an object of type **INetworkSecurityGroup**. My expectation was initially to be no problem if mocking both Azure cmdlets.

I've also tried mocking **Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule** using **-MockWith**:

```
Mock Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule -MockWith {@{NetworkSecurityGroup='test-stuff'}}
```

with no luck.

Can anyone point me to the right direction ?
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE** with full **Describe** statement

First try

```
  $environmentConfig = (Get-AzureEnvironmentConfig "Staging")

  Describe 'Set-NetworkSecurityRuleFromObject' {
    $role = ($environmentConfig.roles | Where { $_.role_name -eq 'Web'})
    $nsgName = Get-NetworkSecurityGroupName -EnvironmentConfig $environmentConfig -Role $role
    $rule = $role.nsg_rules.outbound[0]

    Mock Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup
    Mock Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule

    Set-NetworkSecurityRuleFromObject -NsgName -$nsgName -NsgRule $rule -NsgRuleType "Outbound"

    It 'Should call mocked functions at least once' {
      Assert-MockCalled Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Times 1 -Scope Describe
      Assert-MockCalled Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule -Times 1 -Scope Describe
    }
  }
```

Associated PS module function call:

```
  Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NsgName |
    Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule -Name $NsgRule.name `
      -Type $NsgRuleType `
      # More parameter initialization here ...
      -Protocol $NsgRule.protocol |
    Format-List -Property Name,Location,Label
```

Second try, another implementation of PS function that didn't work:

```
  $nsg = Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NsgName
  $nsg |
    Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule -Name $NsgRule.name `
      -Type $NsgRuleType `
      # More parameter initialization here ...
      -Protocol $NsgRule.protocol |
    Format-List -Property Name,Location,Label
```

Third try

```
  Describe 'Set-NetworkSecurityRuleFromObject' {
    [ ... ]
    Mock Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup { return [PSCustomObject] @{ Name='Any' } }
    Mock Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule

    Set-NetworkSecurityRuleFromObject -NsgName -$nsgName -NsgRule $rule -NsgRuleType "Outbound"

    It 'Should call mocked functions at least once' {
      Assert-MockCalled Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Times 1 -Scope Describe
      Assert-MockCalled Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule -Times 1 -Scope Describe
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post all of your Describe statement?

Comment: @boeprox : I've updated the post with full Describe statement, thanks for your note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still one of the most challenging things to do with Pester.  You need to mock `Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup` in such a way that it returns a valid object to be passed to `Set-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup` later, and figuring out just how to do that can sometimes be tricky.  In this specific case, it's not too bad:

```
Mock Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup {
    return New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Network.NetworkSecurityGroup.Model.SimpleNetworkSecurityGroup('Any', 'someLocation', 'someLabel')
}
```

Since this function parameter is an interface type, you could also write a quick class in C# (or in PowerShell v5) which implements that interface; sometimes this might be more desirable, if the actual class starts doing "stuff" as soon as you create an instance.  However, this `SimpleNetworkSecurityGroup` class doesn't really do anything other than hold data, and it's safe to use as-is.  (Verified with ILSpy.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave, that did the trick, the hardest part was indeed the one with choosing how to mock the result. Great solution !